# nagios socket timeout error in master server

Tags: nagios

I am setting up a Nagios master and its client servers. To make them interact, I am using the `check_nrpe` plugin.

All of the process went fine, but I am getting the following error on the Nagios master server:

```
[root@objects]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost -c  check_ping
CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.
[root@objects]#
```

Because of this error I cannot monitor any other servers.

Someone please help on this :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to monitor your localhost using `nrpe` you also need to install the `nrpe` client. If the client is installed and started the port 5666 should be open. You can verify that using `netstat -an|grep 5666`.

Comment: this is just for a test purpose i did, my localhost is automatically monitored by nagios. acutally i am SSL handshake error.

Comment: to add more point in all the other nagios client. i get this success message [root@ libexec]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost
NRPE v2.15

Comment: i have an another nagios master server where everything runs fine the same check_nrpe is used here, and the result is as expected.[root@nagioshost opt]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost
connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 5666: Connection refused
connect to host localhost port 5666: Connection refused[root@nagioshost opt]#

Comment: can you try to disable SSL by issuing `check_nrpe -n -H localhost`. If that does not help, try to increase the timeout: `check_nrpe -H localhost -t 60`

Comment: as suggested i used -n option, now i am getting the below error.                        CHECK_NRPE: Error receiving data from daemon.

Comment: Apparently SSL must be used. What are the logs `/var/log/messages` and/or `/var/log/syslog` saying when you try to connect using `check_nrpe`?

Comment: Jun 19 15:53:46 ins2ipb00 xinetd[23426]: xinetd Version 2.3.14 started with libwrap loadavg labeled-networking options compiled in.
Jun 19 15:53:46 ins2ipb00 xinetd[23426]: Started working: 0 available services
Jun 19 15:54:01 ins2ipb00 nrpe[23453]: Could not read request from client, bailing out...
Jun 19 16:00:08 ins2ipb00 nrpe[24841]: Could not read request from client, bailing out...
Jun 19 16:02:42 ins2ipb00 nrpe[28111]: Network server bind failure (98: Address already in use)

Comment: The last message indicates that a nrpe process can not spawn correctly since there is already something listening on the configured network port. Did you try to restart `xinetd` for instance to have it initialized correctly?